# how to set valid time period for android c2dm message?

Tags: android, time, android-c2dm

I would like to implement a feature that only delivers messages to devices at specific periods. After the valid time, messages would be abandoned. Can anyone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: You should do some research first and go through a tutorial, [like this](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html). Then come back here with a specific question and show your code where you are having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google just released a new version of c2dm called ["Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)"](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html) at I/O 2012. With GCM its possible to define a timeout for your messages.

GCM ttl section: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/adv.html#ttl

You can find my answer to a similiar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9709944/789738

Answer (score 1):

C2DM itself doesn't have such a facility so you have two choices:

1. Your server app only sends messages during certain times
   or
2. Your Android app receives the C2DM messages all the time, but during certain times you ignore/handle as appropriate.