# C2DM message expiration

Tags: android, timeout, push-notification, android-c2dm

Does anyone know for how long Google will try to deliver a C2DM message before it gives up (even approximately)? 1 week? 2 weeks? 1 day? Of course assume registration is correct and everything but say, the device is offline.

Of course I've already searched to questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473918/how-to-set-a-timeout-expiration-on-a-c2dm-message) but there is no answer to my particular question.

I understand I should have a check myself with an ack of some sort, but I still would like to know when google gives up on delivery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The time Google tries to deliver C2DM messages is approx. 28 days.

Comment: Thanks. Any reference where you got this info from would be highly appreciated.